# Liferay json api add expando value

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm triing to add a value to the custom field i made for a Group. (or site currently). I get a message thats is needs a int and not a string, how can i specify the type in the url?

localhost:8080/api/secure/jsonws/expandovalue/add-value?companyId=10153&className=com.liferay.portal.model.Group&tableName=CUSTOM_FIELDS&columnName=UID&classPK=24049&data=130

The exception i get: 
{"exception":"com.liferay.portlet.expando.ValueDataException: Column 14911 has type custom.field.int and is not compatible with type custom.field.java.lang.String"}

The type of the custom field is a 32bit integer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? any ideas? I'm living something similar but with a date datatype...   "Column 336 has type custom.field.java.util.Date and is not compatible with type custom.field.java.lang.String",  "exception":'com.liferay.portlet.expando.ValueDataException"